# Should I create Edittexts when custom dialogBox is created or before onCreate? Which is more efficient?

Tags: java, android, performance, processing-efficiency, memory-efficient

I have an Android app in which I create a custom dialogBox which is built from an XML file. The custom dialogBox contains 10 different edittext box's. My question is, in my MainActivity.java code, should I create these edittext's when my code creates the custom dialogBox or should I just create them before onCreate? Which one is more efficient/best pratice? Does each have it's own uses?
For example:

**Here**

```
EditText et1;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);...
```

**Or here**

```
public void dialogSettings() {

            final Dialog dialogBox = new Dialog(context);
            dialogBox.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog_settings);
            dialogBox.setTitle(R.string.action_settings);

            EditText et1;

            dialogBox.show();

        }
```

Comment: That's not creation of EditText that is initializing of the edittext

Comment: mmm it's more declaring of an EditText, I haven't initialized it with a value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends where you want to use it. If you are using it inside onCreate only then declare it inside onCreate otherwise define it globally.

Comment: That makes me wonder : let's say I want to load a dialog with a custom view (let's call it `theView`) on the click of a button. Would it be better (performance wise) to load and initialize `theView` on the `onCreate` method or on the `click` method of the button?

Comment: If you think that the button will be clicked various times in the activity it is better to initialize it globally (declare it globally and initialize in onCreate) otherwise initialize it in button onClick method.